# preg_split string into tokens

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to write a regex with which I can split a string into tokens. This used to work:

```
$rawtokens = split("[^-_A-Za-z0-9]+", $string);
```

But now split() has been deprecated (and using preg_split is recommended), this doesn't work:

```
$rawtokens = preg_split("[^-_A-Za-z0-9]+", $string);
```

The error I get is that +\ is an unknown modifier. What's has changed with the migration from split to preg_split?

Answer (score 2):

You need [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for PCRE regexes:

```
$rawtokens = preg_split("/[^-_A-Za-z0-9]+/", $string);
                         ^               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `-` and adding delimiters:

```
$rawtokens = preg_split("/[^\-_A-Za-z0-9]+/", $string);
```

Comment: There is no need to escape the `-` character at the beginning or end of a character class because in those positions its meaning is unambiguous

Comment: @meouw: It's good to develop good regular expression habits.

Comment: you suggested escaping as part of your answer - the escaping is irrelevant here

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T-Regx tool](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx#split-a-string) and you won't need delimiters :)

```
pattern('[^-_A-Za-z0-9]+')->split($string);
```